# Div Flashing before jQuery show or hide

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

On this Page: [http://woocommerce-74099-288162.cloudwaysapps.com/flashing-jquery](http://woocommerce-74099-288162.cloudwaysapps.com/) I have a tab box at the bottom of the page. When you click on the tab buttons on the left the div that is supposed to show flashes at the bottom of the page before it goes into the animation of showing or hiding. My code is basic:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_121_post_13").hide(600);
});
jQuery("#ct_text_block_86_post_13").click(function(){
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_121_post_13").show(600);
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_90_post_13").hide(600);
});
jQuery("#ct_text_block_84_post_13").click(function(){
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_90_post_13").show(600);
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_121_post_13").hide(600);
});
```

I've tried display none with css on the hidden div as well.

Thank You for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The "flashing" is due to both animations occuring at the same time.

If you put the second in the callback of the first, they will occur in sequence.

Try this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_121_post_13").hide(600);
});
jQuery("#ct_text_block_86_post_13").click(function(){
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_90_post_13").hide(600,function(){
    jQuery("#ct_div_block_121_post_13").show(600);
  });
});
jQuery("#ct_text_block_84_post_13").click(function(){
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_121_post_13").hide(600,function(){
    jQuery("#ct_div_block_90_post_13").show(600);
  });
});
```

---

**EDIT**

Since the "flashy bug" is still present, let's try something else.

In `style.css`, comment this part out (using `/*` and `*/` like below):

```
/*
.ct-section::after,
.ct-section-inner-wrap::after,
.ct-div-block::after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  white-space: normal;
}
*/
```

And add:

```
.ct-section,
.ct-section-inner-wrap,
.ct-div-block{
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

When the `div` is hidden, the pseudo-element `:after` dissapears.
[The "flash" can be seen here](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/45000955/Flashy-bug.mp4) at 10% speed... Making it obvious.

Comment: Thanks for sending this... It still flashes thought?

Comment: heheh... Ok, I think the hiding should be done first. I edited.

Comment: That works smoother but there is still a bright flash when you click it. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: I now suspect the pseudo-element `:after`, which make this div displayed as a table to be the cause. But I'm not sure. Do you have access to style.css ?

Comment: I've [recorded this "flashy bug"](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/45000955/Flashy-bug.mp4) and slowered the video to 10% speed. It is now obvious. I'm pretty sure it is due to the `:after` pseudo-element.

Comment: I'm not able to update that part of the css so I added a version below the original that does not have any ::after elements. It still flashes.

Comment: Had to move it to http://woocommerce-74099-288162.cloudwaysapps.com/flashing-jquery

Answer (score 0):

One of the jquery advantage is chaining, I think it will be help you in this

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_121_post_13").hide(600);
});
jQuery("#ct_text_block_86_post_13").click(function(){
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_121_post_13").show(600).jQuery("#ct_div_block_90_post_13").hide(600);
});
jQuery("#ct_text_block_84_post_13").click(function(){
  jQuery("#ct_div_block_90_post_13").show(600).jQuery("#ct_div_block_121_post_13").hide(600);
});
```

Comment: This would hide the div but the second div did not show/get triggered.